# Serialize dynamic type in Asp.Net WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApi with a method that creates a dynamic type as follow:

```
[HttpGet]
public object Foo()
{
AssemblyName asmName = new AssemblyName(string.Format("{0}_{1}", "tmpAsm", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")));
AssemblyBuilder asmBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = asmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("core");
TypeBuilder typeBuilder = GetTempModule().DefineType("MyDynamicClass", TypeAttributes.Public);
Type proxy = typeBuilder.CreateType();

return Activator.CreateInstance(proxy); 
}
```

It seems that the built-in serializer is not able to serialize this class, in fact i get the following error:

> Type 'MyDynamicClass' with data contract name
>   'MyDynamicClass://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/'
>   is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are
>   using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to
>   the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute
>   attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the
>   serializer.

I also tried to mark the dynamic class with the `Serializable` attribute but still not working.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Is it WCF service or Web API ? Can you share the code of MyDynamicClass ?

Comment: It's a WebApi but when I call it with browser I think it uses the WCF serializer instead of the Json serializer. The code of MyDynamicClass is already provided. It's just an empty dynamic class create with the TypeBuilder.

Comment: Does API work fine if you return an object of existing class if the project?